# Creating an archive with current date using 7z command line corrupts the name

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, 7zip

I am trying to set up a 7zip batch file to backup data in an archive with the current date in the file name.

So far I set up

```
@ECHO OFF
7z a C:\Download\%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%_Backupfile.7z -mhe -mx0 -r -ssw -w -i@files_included_in_backup.txt -x@files_excluded.txt
```

pause

The backup itself goes fine, and it should result in a file named JJJ-MM-DD_Backupfile.7z.

Though today on Aug 13 it gives me a file named 2014-8. -01_Backupfile.7z

any idea what´s going wrong?
I am using Windows 8.1 64bit and 7-Zip command line version 9.20.

Comment: From a cmd prompt try this: `echo "%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~4,2%-%DATE:~7,2%"` and paste the result here.

Comment: hi, doing so results in: 2014-8. -01

Comment: can you paste the result of `echo "%date%"`  The problem is that `%date%` is variable from computer to computer, depending on settings and country.  I'll post a robust method in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot:

The first four lines of this code will give you reliable YY DD MM YYYY HH Min Sec variables in XP Pro and higher.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "datestamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%" & set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"

7z a "C:\Download\%datestamp%_Backupfile.7z" -mhe -mx0 -r -ssw -w -i@files_included_in_backup.txt -x@files_excluded.txt
```

Comment: thanks! I tried as described but the filename comes out as \_Backupfile.7z without any date attached.

Comment: thanks! I tried as described but the file comes out as \_.Backupfile.7z without any date attached.

Comment: Try it now.  I typoed the variable name.

Comment: sorry for late reply.

Comment: it results in 2014-8. -01 again.

Comment: Put `echo` before the `7z` command and put `pause` as the last line and run the batch file.  Report what is shown after `c:\download`.

Comment: You must have extra code that is breaking this and if the correct date is not shown then what OS are you using?

Comment: I did a restart again after the last change of the bat-file.

Comment: it works like a charm now! Thank´s a lot for help. Must have been and Windows 8.1 issue.